# Filter array by indices

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array of elements. I also have an IndexSet that specifies which indices of the array need to be extracted into a new array. E.g.:

```
let array = ["sun", "moon", "star", "meteor"]
let indexSet: IndexSet = [2, 3]
// Some magic happens here to get:
let result = ["star", "meteor"]
```

I'm looking to use the swift `filter` function, but haven't got the answer yet. How can I do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`IndexSet` is a collection of increasing integers, therefore you can
*map* each index to the corresponding array element:

```
let array = ["sun", "moon", "star", "meteor"]
let indexSet: IndexSet = [2, 3]

let result = indexSet.map { array[$0] } // Magic happening here!
print(result) // ["star", "meteor"]
```

This assumes that all indices are valid for the given array.
If that is not guaranteed then you can filter the indices
(as @dfri correctly remarked):

```
let result = indexSet.filteredIndexSet { $0 < array.count }.map { array[$0] }
```

Comment: Possibly ensure that none of the indices in the `IndexSet` are out of range for the array onto which elements they are mapped, e.g. `let result = indexSet.filteredIndexSet { $0 < array.count }.map { array[$0] }` (or just `.filter` if we're ok with an intermediate `Int` array of the integer indices).

Comment: Brilliant. Just brilliant.

Comment: Note that because the indices in an `IndexSet` are sorted, the order that they appear in the `indexSet` (not the array literal) is the same order in which they appear in the `array` ;)

Comment: It's stuff like this which is why I love Swift. I was already prepared with `var newArray = [String]()` but now my function returns just one line!

Answer (score 6):

You can use `enumerated`, `filter` and `map` like this

```
let result = array
    .enumerated()
    .filter { indexSet.contains($0.offset) }
    .map { $0.element }
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use `Array.elements(at:)`

```swift
let result = array.elements(at: indexSet)
```

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, `Array` does not have a `elements(at:)` method.

Comment: @MartinR You're right, it's a method defined in a personal extension of `Array`.