# Faster way to get multiple elements from an array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, indexing

Is there a faster/more concise way to get multiple indexes from an array besides looping, and appending? Maybe a one-liner functional variant of the following?

```
let names: [String] = ["John", "Mary", "Hugo", "Bill", "Andrea"]
let indexesToGet = [0, 1, 3]
var result: [String] = []
for i in 0..<indexesToGet.count {
    result.append(names[indexesToGet[i]])
}
return result
//returns ["John", "Mary", "Bill"]
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't make a lot of sense. You don't actually make use of the numbers in `indexesToGet`.

Comment: As rmaddy told `result.append(names[i])` should be `result.append(names[indexToGet[i]])` and output will be `["John", "Mary", "Bill"]`

Comment: Related: [Filter array by indices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40264624/filter-array-by-indices).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can try like this.

```
let result = indexesToGet.map { names[$0] }
```

To prevents from `indexOutOfBounds` crash you can use `flatMap`.

```
let result = indexesToGet.flatMap { names.indicies.contains($0) ? names[$0] : nil}
```

From Swift 4.1 use [`compactMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2950916-compactmap) instead of `flatMap`.

```
let result = indexesToGet.compactMap { names.indicies.contains($0) ? names[$0] : nil}
```

Comment: very nice and neat answer, I wish I could cast you more than one vote up

Comment: @Nirav D I believe `flatMap` in your example s/b `compactMap` now.

Comment: will fail in case of indexesToGet will contain value < 0. But even of this your answer is great. Fixed your answer

Answer (score 1):

usage:

```
names[safe: 10] // returns N's element or nil in case does not exist

names[safeIdxs: 4...15] 

names[safeIdxs: [3,5,9] ]
```

extension:

```
public extension Collection {
    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
    
    subscript(safeIdxs idxArr: [Index] ) -> [Element] {
        return idxArr.compactMap{ self[safe: $0] }
    }
    
    subscript(safeIdxs idxArr: CountableClosedRange<Int> ) -> [Element] {
        return idxArr.compactMap{ $0 as? Index }.compactMap{ self[ safe: $0] }
    }
    
    subscript(safeIdxs idxArr: CountableRange<Int> ) -> [Element] {
        return idxArr.compactMap{ $0 as? Index }.compactMap{ self[ safe: $0 ] }
    }
}
```