# How To remove all Index values from an array other then given in swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift

suppose i have a string array in swift 3 with values

```
var Names:[String] = ["john","Obama","Trump"]
```

in my other number array i have values

```
var index int[]  = [0,2]
```

i want to delete all the values from Names array except index 0 and 2 thats listed in my second numeric array list 
so my result sould like 
["john","Trump"]

i am working in swift 3

Comment: `var index int[]  = [0,2]` isn't legal Swift. You probably meant `let indices = [0, 2]`.

Comment: Compare [Filter array by indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40264624/filter-array-by-indices).

Comment: Dupe @MartinR? It's exactly the same solution regardless of array of indices or `IndexSet` of indices (assuming the array is of increasing indices, as it is in this case).

Answer (score 2):

```
var names = [String]()
var indexes = [Int]()
```

Create `newNames`

```
var newNames = [String]()
```

Populate `newNames`

```
for idx in indexes {
   newNames.append(names[idx])
}
```

Comment: That's really simple and good! Thanks for sharing

Comment: Sure no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

to remove all elements exepts the elements contained in the list indexs:

```
var names = [String]()
names.append("john")
names.append("Obama")
names.append("Trump")

var indexs = [Int]()
indexs.append(0)
indexs.append(2)

var names_res = [String]()


for index in indexs {
       names_res.append(names[index])
}
```

Comment: But he wants to erese only the elements with the indexs in the list indexs, the user who asked didn't specify another thing @MartinR. I don't get your point then, could you explain to me please?

Comment: Ah ok ok... sure... my bad, thank you so much, I corrected it. It should work, right?

Comment: i want to erase element from existing list , dont want to create new array