# How to find selected index values with index array in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I having two Arrays.

1. Index values Array1 = [1,2,3,4]
2. totalarray = [100,20,40,50,76,88,90,76,55,43,32,12,345]

How do I find Array1 index values in totalarray.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. The values in `Array1` don't appear in `totalarray`. Or do you want to treat the values in `Array1` as indexes into `totalarray`?

Comment: What's your expected output? What have you tried?

Comment: Also, note that by strong Swift naming conventions, variable names should start with a lower case letter, and use "camel case." Thus `Array1` should be `array1`, and `totalarray` should be `totalArray`.

Comment: please make your question clear, both the array have different values.

Comment: `indices.map { totalArray[$0] }`.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40264624/filter-array-by-indices

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to find the indexes where each element of `Array1` appears in `totalarray`, you can use a map statement:

```
let Array1 = [1,2,3,4]
let totalarray = [100,20,40,50,76,88,90,76,55,43,32,12,345]

let indexes = Array1.map { totalarray.firstIndex(of: $0) }
print(indexes)
```

Note that **none** of the values in `Array1` appear in `totalArray`, so the above code will put an array of 4 nulls into `indexes`, so the output will be `[nil, nil, nil, nil]`

If you used the sample data from Sanzio Angeli's answer:

```
let Array1 = [7, 6, 4, 8]
let totalarray = [20, 30, 6, 7, 10, 40]
```

The output would be:

```
[Optional(3), Optional(2), nil, nil]
```

The other way to interpret your question is that you want to treat every value in `Array1` as an index into `totalarray`, and want to build an array of the elements at those indexes in totalarray. As mentioned in Sulthan's comment, that could would look like this:

```
let Array1 =  [1,2,3,4]
let totalarray = [100,20,40,50,76,88,90,76,55,43,32,12,345]

let indexes = Array1.map { totalarray[$0] }

print(indexes)
```

And would print the output `[20, 40, 50, 76]`. However that code would crash if any of the values in `Array1` were larger than `totalarray.count - 1`. It really needs range checking.